# Testing drag-and-drop with Watir

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, selenium, watir

I'm evaluating Watir right now. While Selenium has a `dragAndDropToObject` command (which seems to be broken) Watir seems not to have such a command. I couldn't find a script/tutorial with an example of how to test DnD with Watir.

Did anybody try/succeed in testing drag-and-drop with Watir?

Btw.: I am using jQuery for the DnD implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Different people have developed their own extensions to Watir for this. A lot depends on which drag and drop library you are using, apparently. Core Watir does not support drag and drop.

Comment: I think Watir should. For the user drag'n'drop is a clear single operation. It should be also relatively easy to simultate -> mouse down somewhere, mouse move with button pressed, mouse up somewhereelse.

Comment: We would welcome submissions of drag-n-drop support code for Watir. Maybe it should be easy, but our experience is that it is not. If you have a simple solution, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard people talk about it. [Possibilities For New Events in Watir](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Possibilities+For+New+Events+in+Watir) is often mentioned when talking about drag and drop.

I would suggest that you browse these for more information:

- http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general
- http://rubyforge.org/mailman/listinfo/wtr-development